# Share Audio file with VK application

Tags: android, android-intent, android-sharing, vk

I'm trying to share audio files from my android app with other applications including VK: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vkontakte.android&hl=en
The sharing functionality works fine with different applications, but not with VK. The code looks like:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileUri);
    intent.setType(context.getContentResolver().getType(fileUri));
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    context.startActivity(intent);
```

In VK app during uploading process I get just "Error" without any information. In logcat I get the following error:

```
W/vk: com.vkontakte.android.upload.UploadException: can't save photo
                                          at com.vkontakte.android.upload.AudioUploadTask.c(AudioUploadTask.java:95)
                                          at com.vkontakte.android.upload.UploadTask.T_(UploadTask.java:78)
                                          at com.vkontakte.android.upload.UploaderIntentService.a(UploaderIntentService.java:68)
                                          at com.vkontakte.android.upload.UploaderIntentService.onHandleIntent(UploaderIntentService.java:42)
                                          at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:67)
                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
                                          at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

I tried different mime types: "audio/*", "audio/mp3", "application/vnd.package.name", but no success.

Answer (score 2):

I have also faced this issue. I tried to upload my mp3 file manually using VK app user interface and I had the same error as if I did it programmatically via share intent. Looks like VK Android app is just not allowing to upload and attach mp3 files to chat.

Works fine with every other file types.

**Update**

I have just tested and noticed one thing: some mp3 files are uploaded fine but some of them are not allowed. I have 2 ideas why it's happening:

1. VK allows to upload mp3 files of certain length (e.g. min 3 sec, max 30 sec)
2. There a bug in VK Android app which gives error when you upload some mp3 files

Comment: I have the same behaviour. I can upload only one of 20 files. The files are pretty similar. The length no more then 10 sec, they have the same bitrate and so on. So I'm a bit confused.